# How to change destination for an existing aws kinesis Firehose delivery stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have an aws kinesis Firehose delivery stream that was configured with Amazon S3 as destination. I want to change the destination to Amazon Elasticsearch Service but I can't find how to do that in the edit page.
Can I do that or do I need to delete and create new delivery stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note that switching between Amazon ES and other services is not
>   supported. For an Amazon ES destination, you can only update to
>   another Amazon ES destination.

Based on the documentation switching between S3 to ElasticSearch is not supported as of now.

You can update from one ES destination to a different one.

You have to delete and recreate with new elastic search destination.

**Reference:**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/firehose/update-destination.html

Hope it helps.